# iPhone does not allow Javascript or Jquery functionality in an HTML page when loaded in Locally (works fine when loaded from hosted site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, safari

Basic Javascript does not load when opened in iPhone locally

Create any HTML file with even basic HTML alert for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code Referance : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

This basic code also won't Open in iPhone tested in multiple versions

Steps to reproduce:
1) create this file in a desktop any OS Windows, Mac, Linux save it as test.html 
2) send it to your iPhone via airdrop or email or Whatsapp 
3) Load the file - Does not work as expected as it works in the live link (if put on a hosted server it totally works)

Yes Have Enabled JavaScript in Safari on an iPhone
By the way cant even open file in Chrome it says chrome can not handle this link!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the problem. I don't know why this doesn't work, but if your goal is to just test your website locally on an iPhone, I'd recommend to use a localhost. This is how it's done on a Mac:

1. Open Terminal and type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, then hit the enter/return key.
2. Open System Preferences > Network, where you'll find your ip address
3. Open Safari on your iPhone and navigate to [your ip address]:[your port number]

The port number will be displayed in the terminal after step 1. Both devices (Mac and iPhone) must be connected to the same wifi. The URL from step 3 should look similar to this one: 192.168.1.102:8000